# How to read separate lines from a file in PHP (fopen)

Tags: php

The code is taken from hackerrank.com

Content inside file name `php://stdin`

```
5 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Code:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen ("php://stdin", "r");


fscanf($handle, "%i %i", $n, $d);
$a_temp = fgets($handle);
$a = explode(" ",$a_temp);

print_r($a_temp);

?>
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

I am confused, why the code only reads the second line (`i.e 1 2 3 4 5`), not first line? How to read both the lines? or Just first one?

Comment: you mean :  $arr = [
 0 => '1 2 3 4 5',
 1 => '5 4'
];

Comment: Output is: `1 2 3 4 5`, echo = print_r($a_temp)` not `$a`

Comment: Why this code always read the second line of the file???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works just fine.

Each time you call `fscanf` you are reading *one line of the file*. This means that, after `fscanf($handle, "%i %i", $n, $d)` is executed, the file pointer jumps to the second line.

Check variables `$n` and `$d` and both should be equal to `5` and `4`, respectively.

---

If you were to read and parse all lines, avoid using `fscanf` as the pattern is not the same for each line:

```
$handle = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
  $a = explode(" ", $line);
  var_dump($a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get out

```
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin");

$numbers = str_replace("\n", ' ', $handle);
$numbers = explode(' ', $numbers);

foreach($numbers as $key => $value) 
    if($value == '')
        unset($numbers[$key]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($numbers);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 5
)
```